# C# EF Core 5.0 GroupBy Select Conditional Count could not be translated

Tags: c#, ef-core-5.0

I have an Individual Species observation and an Observation group where there is a many-to-many relationship (IndividualObservationGroup). I am now getting an error in the following code since I moved from efcore2.1 to efcore5.0. I am now receiving an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : The LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression:
> KeySelector: i.ObservationGroupGuid,
> ElementSelector:EntityShaperExpression:
> EntityType: IndividualObservationGroup
> ValueBufferExpression:
> ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
> IsNullable: False

```
    .Count(x => x.IndividualObservation.SexCodeId == (Nullable<int>)1)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Here is the code:

```
var queryable = context.IndividualObservationGroup.AsNoTracking()
                       .Include(obg => obg.ObservationGroup)
                       .Include(obg => obg.IndividualObservation)
                           .ThenInclude(io => io.SetDetail)
                       .Where(items => String.Equals(items.ObservationGroupGuid, lookupItem.ObservationGroupGuid) &&
                                                     items.GroupNumber == lookupItem.GroupNumber &&
                                                     items.TargetItem == lookupItem.TargetItem)
                                            .GroupBy(items => items.ObservationGroupGuid)
                                            .Select(items => new
                                            {
                                                TallyKey = items.Key,
                                                Females = items.Count(x => x.IndividualObservation.SexCodeId == 1),
                                                Males = items.Count(x => x.IndividualObservation.SexCodeId == 2),
                                                UnSexed = items.Count(x => x.IndividualObservation.SexCodeId == 3),
                                                numberFromCurrentSet = items.Count(x => x.IndividualObservation.ParentGuid == setDetailGuid)
                                            });
var group = await queryable.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client)

Comment: thanks for the information. I had reviewed the article before. I know that this can be written as an sql statement and run as FromSqlRaw on the database, but prefer not to use a specific SQL statement that may lock me into a specific database (main reason I chose ef core). Also I prefer not pull records to the client (AsEnumerable) and  have a performance hit.

Comment: If I use just  items.Count() then the query runs on the database but by adding any lambda expression, ex. items.Count(x => x.IndividualObservation.SexCodeId == 3) or items.Count(x => x.IndividualObservation.ParentGuid == setDetailGuid), causes an exception by failing to translate. Just trying to understand why.

Comment: You already had the records pulled to the client in 2.1, you just didn't know that. That's what the break changes in 3.0 did, it no longer fallback to client side evaluation, you have to do that explicity.

Comment: I did not know that until I migrated from to 5.0 from 2.1. If I remove the lambda statements in the items.Count() statements (thought logically incorrect) the ef core 5.0 will run it without an exception. But adding the lambda to it, causing the exception: fails to translate. So items.Count() works but items.Count(x => x.IndividualObservation.ParentGuid == setDetailGuid) will not.

Answer (score 0):

After getting come feedback from the efcore github site (https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24238) The recommendation was to introduce the join between the tables, even though I had it specified in the model builder db context code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IndividualObservation>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(x => x.GUID);
                entity.HasMany(x => x.ObservationGroups)
                       .WithOne(e => e.IndividualObservation)
                       .HasForeignKey(e => e.IndividualObservationGuid);
            });
modelBuilder.Entity<ObservationGroup>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(x => x.GUID);
                entity.HasIndex(x => x.GUID);
                entity.HasMany(x => x.IndividualObservations)
                       .WithOne(e => e.ObservationGroup)
                       .HasForeignKey(e => e.ObservationGroupGuid);
            });
modelBuilder.Entity<IndividualObservationGroup>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(io => new { io.IndividualObservationGuid, io.ObservationGroupGuid });
            });
```

The reason given was: "Currently EF Core doesn't expand navigations after a GroupBy operator is applied. You using IndividualObservation navigation hence it fails. As a work-around you can expand navigation manually using join before applying GroupBy and it should work."

So I added the following joins and it works:

```
var queryable = context.IndividualObservationGroup.AsNoTracking()
                       .Include(obg => obg.ObservationGroup)
                       .Include(obg => obg.IndividualObservation)
                           .ThenInclude(io => io.SetDetail)
                       .Join(context.ObservationGroup,
                                 iog => iog.ObservationGroupGuid,
                                 og => og.GUID,
                                 (iog, og) => new {
                                     IndividualObservationGuid = iog.IndividualObservationGuid,
                                     GroupNumber = iog.GroupNumber,
                                     TargetItem = iog.TargetItem,
                                     ObservationGroupGuid = og.GUID
                            })
                        .Join(context.IndividualObservation,
                                     iog => iog.IndividualObservationGuid,
                                     io => io.GUID,
                                     (iog, io) => new {
                                           ObservationGroupGuid = iog.ObservationGroupGuid,
                                           GroupNumber = iog.GroupNumber,
                                           TargetItem = iog.TargetItem,
                                           IndividualObservationGuid = io.GUID,
                                           SetDetailGuid = io.ParentGuid,
                                           SexCodeId = io.SexCodeId
                              })
                       .Where(items => String.Equals(items.ObservationGroupGuid, lookupItem.ObservationGroupGuid) &&
                                                     items.GroupNumber == lookupItem.GroupNumber &&
                                                     items.TargetItem == lookupItem.TargetItem)
                       .GroupBy(items => items.ObservationGroupGuid)
                       .Select(items => new
                                     {
                                        TallyKey = items.Key,
                                        Females = items.Count(x => x.SexCodeId == 1),
                                        Males = items.Count(x => x.SexCodeId == 2),
                                        UnSexed = items.Count(x => x.SexCodeId == 3),
                                        numberFromCurrentSet = items.Count(x => x.SetDetailGuid == setDetailGuid)
                                       });
var group = await queryable.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

So Adding the two join statements allowed me to avoid the IEnumerable requirement and running the query on the client. Just hope that sometime in the future efcore can take more advantage of the joins setup in the modelbuilder statement and use it for IQueryable beyond just navigation.